# VBScript in IBM Personal Communications, Register current date and time

Tags: date, datetime, vbscript

This is a bit complicated to explain but I sure will do my best!

I want to register the current time and date "Year,Week,day + Time", in my program IBM Personal Communications (Session A). I have to use a .MAC extension for the final file in order for the program to read it.

This is the code that I have at the moment:

```
[PCOMM SCRIPT HEADER]
LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT
 DESCRIPTION=
 [PCOMM SCRIPT SOURCE]
 OPTION EXPLICIT
 autECLSession.SetConnectionByName(ThisSessionName)

REM This line calls the macro subroutine
subSub1_

sub subSub1_()
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "151441652 " **<--This is where the date has to appear**

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLPS.WaitForAttrib 12,1,"00","3c",3,10000

   autECLSession.autECLPS.Wait 3401 

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf12]"
end sub
```

autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "151441652 " <--- The final values must appear here in the same order. The numbers have been entered manually by me. So what I essentially need the final program to do is to recognize the date and enter them manually.

This is what the numbers stand for:

15 = The year 2015

14 = The current week, the date right now is 02-04-2015 which is Week 14

4 = Day 4 of the week. thursday

1652 = Current time, I need the time to be a 24hour clock.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: The [DatePart Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kt42529(v=vs.84).aspx) does *literally everything* you want.

Answer (score 0):

[DatePart()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kt42529(v=vs.84).aspx) can do all of this.

```
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys _
    Right(DatePart("yyyy", Now()), 2) & _
    Right("0" & DatePart("ww", Now()), 2) & _
    DatePart("w", Now()) & _
    Right("0" & DatePart("h", Now()), 2) & _
    Right("0" & DatePart("n", Now()), 2)
```

Take note of the optional `FirstDayOfWeek` and `FirstWeekOfYear` parameters, test your edge cases and set those parameters accordingly for the relevant calls.

Comment: Thank you so much! I LOVE YOU!

Comment: Oh yeah, by the way, It didn't work... But it still worked.
The problem right now is that I got this error message: PCSW041 - Not enough systemresources, or also the script engine is installed incorrect.

Comment: I have *absolutely zero* knowledge of IBM Personal Communications, so I am afraid I can't help you with that error.

Comment: No that is fine! I believe that I sort of fixed the problem! On the other hand, the code for displaying the Day of the week is one day off.
It shows Friday in my case when it is Thursday.
So it is 151451908
When I want it to be 151441908

Otherwise it looks great!

Comment: Read the paragraph of text in my answer again.

Comment: Hello again! I am sorry to bother you but I am a total beginner at this!

I tried to play with the code until I get the result but I am not quite sure of what to add... and where.

I guess I should add something here, but I don't know where:

DatePart("w", Now()) & _

Comment: That's correct. I really won't give you any more hints, only that you are 95% there. It will be a lot more satisfying (and useful for you) if you find out at least part of the puzzle yourself.